# Getting all results from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, execute

I am sending sql query to MySQL server.

```
if (self.database_connection.is_connected()):
        cursor = self.database_connection.cursor(prepared=True)

        sql_query = '''
                        SELECT
                            e.ad, e.ad2, e.ad3, e.ad4, eve.ad5
                        FROM
                            db.table2 e
                        JOIN
                            db.table eve
                        ON
                            e.ad1=eve.ad4
                        WHERE 
                            e.ad in ('15965', '1444');
                        
                        '''

            cursor.execute(sql_query)
            row = cursor.fetchall()
```

but it only returns the first record for every element in tuple.
When i query it in Workbench it returns all results - what i mean is for first element in the tuple Workbench returns i.e 2 records, but python returns only first record.

Workbench result:

```
ad     ad2     ad3     ad4         ad5
15965  14      1       2020-04-11  yes
15965  141     NULL    NULL        NULL
1444   41      NULL    NULL        no
```

Python code result:

```
print(row)
[('15965', '14', '1', '2020-04-11', 'yes'),
 ('1444', '41', NULL, NULL, 'no')]
```

I tried with fetchmany and executemany but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: This looks suspiscious: `row = cursor.fetchall()`/ `print(row)`. What you are getting isn't one row, but several rows, so I'd expect something along the lines of: `rows = cursor.fetchall()` / `for row in rows: ...`.

Comment: it's just a name of variable - doesn't have anything to do with that

Comment: Okay, sorry. Can you please show the involved rows of the two tables? And then, please correct your query. It is invalid, because of table alias mismatches t / t2 vs. e / eve.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want aggregation.  It looks like:

```
SELECT e.ad, MIN(e.ad2), MIN(e.ad3), MIN(e.ad4), MIN(eve.ad5)
FROM db.table2 t2 JOIN
     db.table t 
     ON e.ad1 = eve.ad4
WHERE e.ad in ('15965', '1444')
GROUP BY e.ad;
```

The column aliases in your query are inconsistent.  I assume you know how to fix that.

Comment: I don't understand why use MIN() function? And to be honest don't see much diffrence between my and your query. I updated the table names.

Comment: @jan . . . The key is the `GROUP BY` (which I just added).

Comment: yeah i see apparently after adding GROUP BY to my sql query Workbench returns same results as python code ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my dumbness I was querying Workbench production table and python was querying development table...

Comment: Haha, that explains it. I am glad you found the reason and posted this answer. You should accept it (with the tick next to this answer), so future readers see quickly what all this was about.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner surly i will, but: `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`